# Guild Wars 2 Critical Chance in PvP

Tags: guild-wars-2

For the Mesmer in GW 2 with various runes at level 80 it will have a very high crit chance in PvE somewhere in the neighborhood of 50-60% depending on what weapons used. Ferocity is at 170,  but the moment you enter the Mists for PvP the Perception takes a huge hit and therefore Crit Chance goes down to 1% and ferocity goes down to 18. No change in gear.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PvE and PvP uses separate builds.
When you enter Heart of the Mists, make sure to click on the left icon at the top of the screen in the middle (should say "PvP build" when you hover over it) and adjust your runes and traits accordingly.